# Tangent Line for Polar Curve R=$3-3\sin\theta $

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I start by changing polar coords into $x$ and $y$ and then find the derivatives to get the slope.
\begin{equation}
x=(3-3\sin\theta)\cos\theta
=3\cos\theta -3\cos\theta \sin\theta
\end{equation}
and took
\begin{align}
x'& =(-3\sin\theta +3\sin^2\theta -3\cos^2\theta ) \\
& = -3(\sin\theta -\sin^2\theta +\cos^2\theta) \\
& = -3\sin\theta +3
\end{align}
and 
\begin{gather}
y = (3-3\sin\theta)\sin\theta
= 3\sin\theta -3\sin^2\theta \\
y'=3\cos\theta -3\cos^2\theta
\end{gather}
Now that I got the (hopefully) correct derivatives I need to find the tangent line for $\theta =\frac{3\pi }{4}$, so I plug $\theta =\frac{3\pi }{4}$ into $\frac{3\cos\theta -3\cos^2\theta }{-3\sin\theta +3}$ and got $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ for the slope.

How do I get the tangent line though?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Your algebra seems right.

Comment: What's the meaning of $x'$ and $y'$?